# Numeric Range Query

Tags: java, lucene

I read that for handling date range query NumericRangeQuery is better than TermRangeQuery in "Lucene in action", But i couldnot find the reason. i want to know the reason behind it.
I used TermRangeQuery and NumericRangequery both for handling date range query and i found that searching is fast via NumericRangeQuery.

My second point is to query using NumericRangeQuery i have to create indexes using NumericField by which i can create indexes upto milisecond but what if i want to reduce my resolution upto hour or day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Why is numeric so much faster than term?

As you have noted, there is a "precision step". This means that numbers are only stored to a certain precision, which means that there is a (very) limited number of terms. According to the documentation, it is rare to have more than 300 terms in an index. Check out the wikipedia article on [Tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) if you are interested in the theory.

- How can you reduce precision?

The [NumericField](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html) class has a "precision" parameter in the constructor. Note that the range query also has a precision parameter, and they must be the same. That JavaDoc page has a link to a paper written about the implementation explaining more of what precision means.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation by @Xodarap about Numeric field is correct. Essentially, the precision is dropped for the numbers to reduce the actual term space. Also, I suppose, TermRangeQuery uses String comparison whereas NumericRange query is working with integers. That should squeeze some more  performance.

You can index at any desirable resolution - millisecond to day. `Date.getTime()` gives you milliseconds since epoch. You can divide this number by 1000 to get time with resolution at second. Or you can divide by 60,000 to get resolution at minute. And so on.

Comment: Note that the precision parameter will affect this. Even if you pass in the seconds, if you have precision = 4 and you're using a long, it will store only about 500 different values. So if you have multiple values per day, every day for two years, you will be unable to store more than the day, no matter how precise the values you pass in are.

Comment: @Xodarap: Precision step has no bearing on how many different values you can store. Values are stored exactly as they're provided. Precision steps simply define how quickly queries can find a range of numbers. The lower the precision number, the faster the query, but the larger the index. The higher the precision number, the slower the query, but the smaller the index. Good explanation at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19236339/1145177