# Solr date field tdate vs date?

Tags: date, solr

So I have a question about Solr's field date types which is pretty straight forward: what's the difference between a 'date' field and a 'tdate' one?

The schema .xml claims that 'For faster range queries, consider the tdate type' and 'A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date faceting. '
Fair enough... but what's the precisionStep="6" all about? should i change this? does it change the way i would create the query in case I use the tdate? What's the real advantage or what does Solr do that makes it better?

P.S went through google, Solr manual, solr wiki and the java docs without any luck so I'd appreciate a kind and explanatory answer :)...
Also checked:
http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/05/13/exploring-lucene-and-solrs-trierange-capabilities/
http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/AAfXfqRYyLnDFtskmLRi

Comment: 5 year later, still the same situation with google, Solr manual, solr wiki, etc. Oh, no, something's changed:  Google now points here :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically trie ranges are faster. [Here](http://epic.awi.de/21049/1/Sch2009g.pdf) is one explanation. With precisionStep you configure how much your index can grow to get the performance benefits. To quote from the link you are referring:

> More importantly, it is not dependent on the index size, but instead the precision chosen.

and

> the only drawbacks of TrieRange are a little bit larger index sizes, because of the additional terms indexed

Answer (score 41):

Trie fields make range queries faster by precomputing certain range results and storing them as a single record in the index. For clarity, my example will use integers in base ten. The same concept applies to all trie types. This includes dates, since a date can be represented as the number of seconds since, say, 1970.

Let's say we index the number `12345678`. We can tokenize this into the following tokens.

```
12345678
123456xx
1234xxxx
12xxxxxx
```

The `12345678` token represents the actual integer value. The tokens with the `x` digits represent ranges. `123456xx` represents the range `12345600` to `12345699`, and matches all the documents that contain a token in that range.

Notice how in each token on the list has successively more `x` digits. This is controlled by the precision step. In my example, you could say that I was using a precision step of 2, since I trim 2 digits to create each extra token. If I were to use a precision step of 3, I would get these tokens.

```
12345678
12345xxx
12xxxxxx
```

A precision step of 4:

```
12345678
1234xxxx
```

A precision step of 1:

```
12345678
1234567x
123456xx
12345xxx
1234xxxx
123xxxxx
12xxxxxx
1xxxxxxx
```

It's easy to see how a smaller precision step results in more tokens and increases the size of the index. However, it also speeds up range queries.

Without the trie field, if I wanted to query a range from 1250 to 1275, Lucene would have to fetch 25 entries (`1250`, `1251`, `1252`, ..., `1275`) and combine search results. With a trie field (and precision step of 1), we could get away with fetching 8 entries (`125x`, `126x`, `1270`, `1271`, `1272`, `1273`, `1274`, `1275`), because `125x` is a precomputed aggregation of `1250` - `1259`. If I were to use a precision step larger than 1, the query would go back to fetching all 25 individual entries.

**Note:** In reality, the precision step refers to the number of bits trimmed for each token. If you were to write your numbers in hexadecimal, a precision step of 4 would trim one hex digit for each token. A precision step of 8 would trim two hex digits.

Comment: Awesome explanation. I've been reading for hours trying to understand precision steps, and this is the first explanation that made sense.

Comment: Note that seconds since 1970 isn't just a theoretical way to do this. It's indeed the way it's done, and if you have a null date field, it will be considered 0 seconds from 1970. The result is ordering null and non null trie date fields is terrible. You get dates before 1970, null values, then dates after 1970.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to just look at the source code. Some of the things for Solr aren't well documented and the fastest way to get a trustworthy answer is to simply look at the code. If you haven't been in the code yet, that too is to your benefit. At least in the long run.

Here's a link to the TrieTokenizerFactory.

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/solr/solr-core/1.4.1/solr-core-1.4.1-sources.jar!/org/apache/solr/analysis/TrieTokenizerFactory.java?format=ok

The javadoc in the class at least hints at the purpose of the precisionStep. You could dig futher.

EDIT: I dug a bit further for you. It's passed off directly to Lucene's NumericTokenStream class, which will used the value during parsing the token stream. Probably worth closer examination. It seems to deal with granularity and is probably a tradeoff between size in the index and speed.

Comment: Neat, thanks for the responses... I also found a nice post in Lucene forums, which clarifies a bit more what's the deal with the tdate... Apparently, it's just the way Solr indexes the field and the size of it:

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Best-performance-for-facet-dates-in-trunk-using-solr-TrieDateField-td487668.html

Apart from the index size and performance wise options, I haven't found any other stuff that would need to be changed in case you use the tdate option.